# How to save data from JSON to a variable in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new in Node.js, I have a problem.

I would like to save data from JSON object which I have downloaded from github API.

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var github = require('octonode');
var client = github.client();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

app.get('/getUsers', function (req, response) {

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
   var result;

   client.get('/users/angular/repos', {}, function (err, status, body, headers) { 
       result = response.write(JSON.stringify(body));
       console.log(result); //JSON object
       return result;
});

console.log(result); //undefined

});
```

How can I save an data from object to single variable?

(I want to then transform it to an Array and take some useful data).

Comment: If you are stringifying `body`, isn't  `body` already an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get result outside of the asynchronous call as it is not yet defined. To get this value either call a method inside the callback of query or use async module and pass it.

```
app.get('/getUsers', function (req, response) {

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
   var result;

   client.get('/users/angular/repos', {}, function (err, status, body, headers) { 
       result = response.write(JSON.stringify(body));
       console.log(result); //JSON object
       doSomeOperationOnResult(result)
});
});

function doSomeOperationOnResult(result){
//Your operating code
}
```